# WSO2 IS: Access Control Policy for a Service Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IS 5.3.0:
UseCase: Register a Service Provider for OpenID Connect with code, implicit and password grant types. In addition "Enable Authorization" is activated which basically limits the access to the Relying Party via a role based XACML policy.

It works fine for code and implicit flows as they go via the front channel (browser).  The policy does not get evaluated when using password flow. 
Is that by design or is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of the password grant type flow.

Comment: Do you know details about that "design decision"?  Does it make sense to restrict access to a service provider via one flow and allowing it via another?